# Getting both of intersection and union at the same time

Tags: typescript

I have these two interfaces:

```
export interface ResLogin {
    e: "already logged in" | "fail";
    ticket: string;
}

export interface ResException {
    e: "exception";
    msg: string;
    stack: string;
}
```

and I want a type that have all members of ResLogin and ResException, while 'e' field have possible values of "already logged in", "fail" and "exception".

This is my attempt:

```
export type ResLoginClient = ResLogin & ResException;
export type ResLoginClient2 = ResLogin | ResException;
```

However both have problems:

```
let r: ResLoginClient;
r.e // r.e has 'never' type
r.msg // r.msg exists and that's good

let r2: ResLoginClient2;
r2.e // type of r2.e is "already logged in" | "fail" | "exception"
r2.msg // but r2.msg does not exists
```

I want some way of declaring a type so that

```
let r3:????
r3.e // type of r3.e is "already logged in" | "fail" | "exception"
r3.msg // exists
r3.ticket // exists
```

How can I declare such type?

Comment: Is `r3.msg` supposed to be a `string` or something like `string | undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your use case exactly so it's possible this type function isn't exactly what you need:

```
type Combine<U> = {
  [K in U extends any ? keyof U : never]: U extends { [P in K]?: any }
    ? U[K]
    : undefined
};

type ResLoginClient = Combine<ResLogin | ResException>;
// type ResLoginClient = {
//    e: "already logged in" | "fail" | "exception";
//    ticket: string | undefined;
//    msg: string | undefined;
//    stack: string | undefined;
// }
```

or, if you don't want those `undefined` properties, you can do

```
type Combine<U> = {
  [K in U extends any ? keyof U : never]: U extends { [P in K]?: any }
    ? U[K]
    : never // undefined became never here
};

type ResLoginClient = Combine<ResLogin | ResException>;
// type ResLoginClient = {
//    e: "already logged in" | "fail" | "exception";
//    ticket: string;
//    msg: string;
//    stack: string;
// }
```

Hope one of those is useful to you; good luck!

---

UPDATE: now that I know that these types are useful to you, I can explain anything that's confusing about how they work.  There are [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types in there, so you might want to read up on those for more details.

So `Combine<U>` is a mapped type, whose keys are `U extends any ? keyof U : never`.  That's a [distributed conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) which is *not* just the same as `keyof U` (which would just be `"e"` as you noted).  Since the `U` in `U extends any` is a bare type parameter, if `U` is a union type, the compiler will split the union up into its constituents, do the conditional type for each one, and then make a union of the results.  So when `U` is `ResLogin | ResException`, the conditional type `U extends any ? keyof U : never` is evaluated as

```
(ResLogin extends any ? keyof ResLogin : never) | 
(ResException extends any ? keyof ResException : never)
```

or

```
(keyof ResLogin) | (keyof ResException)
```

So what I've done is *distribute* the `keyof` function over the union in `U`.  And thus `K` of the mapped type will iterate over the keys that appear in at least one constituent of `U`.

The properties in the mapped type are similarly distributed.  We have `U extends { [P in K]? any } ? U[K] : undefined`.  This becomes, for our `U`, `(ResLogin extends {[P in K]?: any} ? ResLogin[K] : undefined)` | `(ResException extends {[P in K]?: any} ? ResException[K] : undefined)`.  This is evaluated for each `K` in the mapped type, so let's just look at one for concreteness, say `"ticket"`.  The mapped type `{[P in K]?: any}` where `K` is just `"ticket"` is evaluated to the concrete type `{ticket?: any}`.  So the `"ticket"` property of `Combine<U>` will be evaluated as:

```
(ResLogin extends {ticket?: any} ? ResLogin['ticket'] : undefined) |
(ResException extends {ticket?: any} ? ResException['ticket'] : undefined)
```

Now `ResLogin` *does* extend `{ticket?: any}`, and `ResException` *does not* extend `{ticket?: any}`, so that property is evaluated as:

```
(ResLogin['ticket']) | (undefined)
```

So `ResLogin` contributes its `"ticket"` property, and `ResException` contibutes `undefined`.  If, instead of `"ticket"`, we look at `"e"`, which appears in both union constituents, the property will become:

```
(ResLogin['e']) | (ResException['e'])
```

and there won't be an `undefined` in there.

Hope that makes sense now.  Good luck again!

Comment: Thanks it works and I'm trying to understand the code! I prefer 'undefined' one.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding though.
`K in U` seems to evaluate so that K is one of `ResLogin`, `ResException`.

Comment: **However, why is it `keyof U` not `keyof K`?**

Comment: I thought `keyof U` would only resolve to 'e' not all of [ 'e', 'ticket', 'msg', 'stack' ].

Comment: Thanks for your generous answer, @jcalz! After reading the links on distributed conditional type and ur update, it makes sense now.